# are objects still valid after std::move

Tags: c++, vector, stl, move

I've seen so many questions about status of an object after std::move(). But what if the object, for example, a vector, is really moved by move semantics ?

for example :

```
//assuming that vecA vecB and vecC are vectors.

vecA = std::move(vecB);

//some other code...

vecB = vecC;// legal or not?
```

or a more simple example:

```
vecA = std::move(vecB);

//try to take back control of resource

vecB = std::move(vecA)
```

Is it possible to do it ?

Comment: It's perfectly valid. `std::vector` after being moved-from is guaranteed to be valid and `empty()`.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen
 thanks for your help !

Comment: What `move` does depends on the class. In general, most classes (and all standard ones) are designed to be assignable after being moved from. The difference between classes usually lies in whether they are empty after being moved from or remain in an "valid but unspecfied state".

Comment: All standard library objects (including `std::vector`) that are moved from are left in a valid but (unless explicitly specified) unspecified state.   This doesn't (necessarily) mean `empty()` is true or that `.size()` is zero.    It does mean that the object may be assigned to  (e.g. `vecA = another_vector`), may be cleared (e.g. `vecA.clear()` or `vecA.resize(0)`) and, importantly, may be safely destructed.

Comment: An object is never "really moved", and `std::move` does not actually do anything - it is just a type cast. What "move semantics" means is that some object may take over some other object's resources, if it so wishes. That is, it is ownership that (potentially) moves, not the "moved" object.

Comment: Yes they are in a state where they can be destructed, and even be moved to again. Just look at the implementation of `std::swap(T&& lhs, T&& rhs)`. And it is up to the developer if a moved from object still represents a valid resource or not, and if for example the moved from object should still accept calls. std::move by itself only returns an rvalue-reference, which can be picked up by move constructors or functions

Comment: How move operator= (if it exists) leaves the moved from object depends on type. The std::vector leaves it in valid but unspecified state, std::unique_ptr in empty state, std:thread in not representing a thread state. It is usually good idea to specify the state for your own classes to be some intuitively "empty" / "not available" state.

Comment: The `std::vector` is explicitly specified to be left in a specified state.  This means `.empty()` will be true, and that `.size()` is zero.  Most other standard C++ library objects are just guaranteed to be in a *valid but unspecified* state, suitable for destruction or being assigned to.